# Mongoose Object has no method save

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

before i post this question i already done many search on google, but still nothing help. so my problem is, i want to update my database after querying, the object has created, before, but whenever i want to update it, there is an error that say my object has no method save.

```
TypeError: Object { session_key: '-----',
poll_id: '-----',
status: 'xxxxx',
_id: xxxx,
__v: 0 } has no method 'save'
at Promise.<anonymous> (/home/albert/gampangpoll/server.js:971:18)
at Promise.<anonymous> (/home/albert/gampangpoll/node_modules/mongoose/node_ modules/mpromise/lib/promise.js:177:8)
at Promise.emit (events.js:95:17)
at Promise.emit (/home/albert/gampangpoll/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules /mpromise/lib/promise.js:84:38)
at Promise.fulfill (/home/albert/gampangpoll/node_modules/mongoose/node_modu les/mpromise/lib/promise.js:97:20)
at /home/albert/gampangpoll/node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:1056:26
at model.Document.init (/home/albert/gampangpoll/node_modules/mongoose/lib/d ocument.js:254:11)
at completeMany (/home/albert/gampangpoll/node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js :1054:12)
at Object.cb (/home/albert/gampangpoll/node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:10 20:11)
at Object._onImmediate (/home/albert/gampangpoll/node_modules/mongoose/node_ modules/mquery/lib/utils.js:137:16)
```

here is my mongoose schema:

```
var RoomSchema = new Schema ({
 status : String,
 session_key : String,
 poll_id : String,
 jml_peserta : Number
});
```

and here is where the code produce error:

```
Room.find({'session_key': input_skey}, function(err, room){
 room.jml_peserta += 1;
 room.save();
```

i have tried to change the object name from room to liveroom just in case its case insensitive, but, still nothing changes. i also trying another way, hours of debugging but the problem still persist. please help me, thank you very much.

Comment: You should not be doing this anyway. Look at the documentation for [**`$inc`**](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/inc/). That is an atomic update method, and much safer than what you are doing.

Answer (score 1):

With `find`, the `room` parameter to the callback will be an *array* of docs, not just one.  Switch to using `findOne` instead:

```
Room.findOne({'session_key': input_skey}, function(err, room){
  room.jml_peserta += 1;
  room.save();
});
```

But like Blakes commented, you should be using an atomic `update` to make this type of change instead:

```
Room.update({'session_key': input_skey}, 
            {$inc: {jml_peserta: 1}},
            function(err, numAffected){ ... });
```

Answer (score 0):

`find` gives you an array of docs.

If you are sure that there exists only one document with that `session_key` and want to use `save` you can use the below script.

```
Room.find({'session_key': input_skey}, function(err, room){
    room.jml_peserta += 1;
    room[0].save();
}
```

However you can use `findOneAndUpdate` to find a single document and update. The advantage of findOneAndUpdate over update is you can use the document to send the response etc.

```
Room.findOneAndUpdate({'session_key': input_skey},
    {$inc: {jml_peserta: 1}},
      function (err, room) {
         //Your code
      }
   );
```

If you just don't want the document you can use `update`

```
Room.update({'session_key': input_skey},
    {$inc: {jml_peserta: 1}},
      function (err, numberOfUpdates) {
         //Your code
      }
   );
```